# Choose array element or remove the first two

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, wordpress, thumbnails

I'm adapting a wordpress plugin that generates thumbnails.
Thanks to this website I have advanced pretty, but I'm stuck on a problem.
The plugin generates a thumbnail from the first image in the post. I need that generated from the third image.

content of post

```
[URL=http://example.com/viewer.php?file=3030128910131424.jpg]      [IMG]http://example.com/images/30301289149131424_thumb.jpg[/IMG][/URL] [URL=http://example.com/viewer.php?file=6331951274718152.jpg][IMG]http://example.com/images/7633127470118152_thumb.jpg[/IMG][/URL]
```

the original code

```
// Initialize variable used to store list of matched images as per provided regular expression
$matches = array(); 

// Get all images from post's body
preg_match_all('/\[img\]([^\[\]>]*)/i', $post[0]->post_content, $matches); 

if (count($matches)) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $image) {
        /**
         * If the image is from wordpress's own media gallery, then it appends the thumbmail id to a css class.
         * Look for this id in the IMG tag.
         */
        preg_match('/wp-image-([\d]*)/i', $image, $thumb_id);
        $thumb_id = $thumb_id[1];

        // If thumb id is not found, try to look for the image in DB. Thanks to "Erwin Vrolijk" for providing this code.
        if (!$thumb_id) {
            $image = substr($image, strpos($image, '"')+1);
            $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE guid = '".$image."'");
            $thumb_id = $result[0]->ID;
        }

        // Ok. Still no id found. Some other way used to insert the image in post. Now we must fetch the image from URL and do the needful.
        if (!$thumb_id) {
            $thumb_id = apt_generate_post_thumb($matches, $key, $post[0]->post_content, $post_id);
        }

        // If we succeed in generating thumg, let's update post meta
        if ($thumb_id) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $thumb_id );
            break;
        }
    }
}
}// end apt_publish_post()

 /**
  * Function to fetch the image from URL and generate the required thumbnails
 */

 function apt_generate_post_thumb($matches, $key, $post_content, $post_id)
 { 
 // Make sure to assign correct title to the image. Extract it from img tag
$imageTitle = '';
preg_match_all('/<\s*img [^\>]*title\s*=\s*[\""\']?([^\""\'>]*)/i', $post_content, $matchesTitle);

if (count($matchesTitle) && isset($matchesTitle[1])) {
    $imageTitle = $matchesTitle[1][$key];
}

// Get the URL now for further processing

$imageUrl = $matches[1][$key];
$imageUrl = str_replace("_thumb", "", $imageUrl);
```

I've tried two things

```
// Get the URL now for further processing

$imageUrl = $matches[3][$key];
$imageUrl = str_replace("_thumb", "", $imageUrl);
```

Does not generate thumbnail.

And now I'm trying to remove the first two array variables, before obtaining the url. I have tried array_splice and array_slice but I get no results. 
Any idea to create the thumbnail from the third image and not the first? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `explode($matches)` and than run your `procedure` on the "second" element which is on `3` in `0 1 2` count.

Comment: I tried 0,2,3,4,5 and does not generate the thumbnail .. just with 1, I do not know why